# Puppet template if defined syntax

Tags: unix, puppet

I am having trouble finding a solution in Puppet documents. I am trying to define a variable in Puppet template. For example:

If `class graylog2` and `apache` are defined in node class section then the template puts these variables in the config file:

```
# Apache logging
local5.* @<%= @server_gl -%>:<%= @service_port_gl -%> <- This part has to inserted if defined graylog2 class and apache class in node file
local5.info ~
local5.err ~

# Nginx logging
local4.* @<%= @server_gl -%>:<%= @service_port_gl -%> <- This part has to be inserted if defined graylog2 class and apache class in node file
local4.info ~
local4.err ~
```

Example:

```
if defined (Class['apache', 'graylog2'])
    # Nginx logging
    local4.* @<%= @server_gl -%>:<%= @service_port_gl -%>
    local4.info ~
    local4.err 
else
    # Nginx logging
    local4.info ~
    local4.err
```

I am not 100% sure, but I guess the example version would not work. 
Also how could I get `@server_gl` from `graylog2 module` so it does not have to be defined in `syslog module`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

```
# Apache logging
<% if classes.include?("httpd") %>
local5.* @<%= scope.function_hiera(["ls_gelf_host"]) %>:<%= @service_port -%> 
local5.info ~
local5.err ~
<% else %>
local5.info ~
local5.err ~
<% end %>

# Nginx logging
<% if classes.include?("nginx") %>
local4.* @<%= scope.function_hiera(["ls_gelf_host"]) %>:<%= @service_port -%> 
local4.info ~
local4.err ~
<% else %>
local4.info ~
local4.err ~
<% end %>
```

Comment: Is `$classes` defined in your manifest? Is it actually `hiera_array("classes")`?

Comment: $classes is defined in my manifest.

Comment: Okay, then this is probably a safe thing to do. Do use `@classes` rather than `classes` in your templates.

Comment: I use classes in my templates

Comment: I can see that. You should prefix Puppet variables with an `@` in your templates, though. Use without `@` is deprecated and will no longer work in Puppet `4.x`.

Comment: Sorry I miss read your question and yes I do use @classes.